# Google Drive appdata and Children.Delete

Tags: google-drive-api, appdata

Looks like items under appdata folder can't be deleted with DirectoryService.Children.Delete - got error "Method not supported for appdata contents [403]". Just wondering why this limit? Should appdata folder behave the same like other folders?

Answer (score 0):

`appdata` is a regular Drive file with some restrictions. Restricting the deletion of the child references is one of them.

Deleting a child reference is going to make that file/directory orphan if the file is in the appdata -- which is not true for the rest of the regular Drive files because they are still discoverable by the user. That's why instead of removing the hierarchal link by removing the child reference, you should always delete the directory contents. You should recursively use [`files.delete`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) to remove an appdata directory and its children.